# PHP curl do not refresh after form submit or keep in session, or xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, forms, curl, xmlhttprequest

Sorry a newbie to PHP, I'm trying to do a curl form submit but want to keep the results after the first submit. These then display buttons and depending which button is clicked another submit displays the second values in a popup. Its passing the values to the popup correctly but I dont want the screen to be refreshed when the second submit is clicked.

Any pointers be appreciated

```
<?php session_start();
?>

<html>
 <head>

  <title>PHP Test</title>

 </head>
 <body>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

  function popup(mylink, windowname)
  {
  if (! window.focus)return true;
  var href;
  if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
     href=mylink;
  else
     href=mylink.href;
  window.open(href, windowname, 'width=700,height=235,scrollbars=yes');
  return false;
  }

  </SCRIPT>

  <form action="index.php" method="post">

    CHECK DOMAIN:
    <input type="text" input name="checkDomain" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['checkDomain']) ? $_POST['checkDomain'] : '' ?>"/>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Check</button>

<?php

$DomainArray = array("ie","com","net");

//IF WE WANT TO PARSE XML RESPONSE
function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    try {
        $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong.
        $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) {
            $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
        }
        trigger_error($error_message);
        return false;
    }

    return $xmlTree;
}
if(!empty($_POST)) {}{


if(!empty($_POST["checkDomain"])) {
$checkDomain = $_POST["checkDomain"];

if(!empty($_POST["form2-submit"])) {
$whoIs = $_POST['form2-submit'];
}

 if ($checkDomain !=null || $whoIs !=null)
 {
    //Check if a TLD has been entered
    if (strpos($checkDomain, '.') !== FALSE)
    {

        $domain = substr($checkDomain, 0, strpos($checkDomain, "."));
        $DomainList = substr($checkDomain, strpos($checkDomain, ".")+1);


        $url =  'check1';

    }

 else if  (!empty($_POST['form2-submit'])) {
$WhoisDomain = $DomainArray[$whoIs-1];
    $url = 'check2';
    }

 else{
    echo ' Checking all domains:';
        $DomainList = implode(",",$DomainArray);
        $url =  'check3';

   }
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$cont = produce_XML_object_tree($xml);
}

$_SESSION["otherXML"] =$xml;

    foreach( $cont->Domain as $domain){
        print '<br/>'.(string)$domain;

    }


$index = 0;
    foreach( $cont->RRPText as $rRPText ){
    $index++;
        print '<br/>'.(string)$rRPText;
        //echo 'index'.$index;
        if ($rRPText == "Domain not available")
        {

        print ' <button type="submit" name="form2-submit" onclick="popup(\'popup.php\')" value="'.$index.'">whois </button> ';

        }

    }
}

?>
  </form>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want a "*screen refresh*" on submit you need to look into making an [Asynchronous Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: thanks i've being trying to do async http request put cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to be refreshed you should make an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) call.

To make life easier you could use [jQuery's POST](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) .

Answer (score 0):

I've being trying to use httpRequest to do it async but there nothing being returned? API says return can be  Text, HTML, or XML. I've tried them all.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function httpGetAsync()
  {
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "URL....", true);
        xmlHttp.send( null );
alert(xmlHttp);
 alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
  </SCRIPT>
```